# Excel VBA populating a list box with values from selected sheet using loops

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 listboxes in a userform. When the user clicks on an item (a worksheet name) in one of the boxes, the other list box should autopopulate with values in the D column of the specific worksheet they have selected. I also dont want any duplicate values to show up. How can i accomplish this by using loops?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, we won't write code for you. I recommend you read about Loops, Ranges or Cells and Listbox Items in VBA. If you get stuck on a specific problem, please come back with a specific example (including code) and we'll be glad help. Good luck!

Comment: For example, you can get the data from D1 by using Sheets(1).Range("D1").value, and can move down the D column by using the Offset() function. Hopefully this helps get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few things are going to have to happen here.

Since you failed to state the names of your listboxes, we are using the generic forms:

- `ListBox1` is the list box with your sheet names
- `ListBox2` is the list box to auto-populate from column D

First, you will need to ensure that `listBox1` is initialized with your worksheet values. A sample of how you could do this is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'MUST BE PLACED IN USERFORM CODE MODULE!!
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws

End Sub
```

The above is not required for your task, but your userform being pre-populated **is required**.

Now you are going to want to watch for the `ListBox1_Change()` event. Again, if your listbox isn't named `ListBox1`, then you will need to change this in the Sub Name.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

    'MUST BE PLACED IN USERFORM CODE MODULE!!
    Dim wsSelected As Worksheet
    Set wsSelected = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ListBox1.Value)

    With wsSelected

        Me.ListBox2.List = rngToUniqueArr(.Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells( _
                lastRow(wsSelected, "D"), "D")))

    End With

End Sub

Function rngToUniqueArr(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant
    'Reference to [Microsoft Scripting Runtime] Required
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        dict(cel.Value) = 1
    Next cel
    rngToUniqueArr = dict.Keys
End Function

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

The sub `rngToUniqueArr` is something I have stored in my **PERSONAL.XLSB** workbook, it's a useful function to have. This will take an input range and create a dictionary of unique values, and output into an array.

> The Above requires a reference to be set to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in **Tools** > **References**

In your `ListBox1_Change()` event, the `wsSelected` is the worksheet you selected from `ListBox1`, and you are adding the array from the `rngToUniqueArr` into `ListBox2`.